# Module.Loader function breaks webpart

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-addin

I need to import css file from remote so I use Module.Loader(its spfx&react project generated by yeoman);

```
public render(): React.ReactElement<IFooterProps> {
      ModuleLoader.loadCss('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css');
...
```

And the picture below is what my working fine web part is tranlated. How can I add remote css libraries?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** - Saw you git code and scratched my head for couple of days, this is how i was able to load it from CDN

In your webpart code, you need to add below line:

```
import { SPComponentLoader } from '@microsoft/sp-loader';
```

After that you can add your code as below:

```
export default class AnnouncementsWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IAnnouncementsWebPartProps> {

  public constructor() {
    super();

    SPComponentLoader.loadCss('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css');

  }


   public render(): void {
    const element: React.ReactElement<IAnnouncementProperties> = React.createElement(Announcements, {
      httpClient: this.context.spHttpClient,
      siteUrl: this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl,
      listName: "announcement2",//Announcements
      description: this.properties.description,
      annCount:this.properties.annCount
    });

    ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
  }
```

After that, just gulp serve. At my end, it loads the font awesome from cdn.

[image]

Reference - [Add jQueryUI Accordion to your SharePoint client-side web part](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/blob/master/docs/spfx/web-parts/get-started/add-jqueryui-accordion-to-web-part.md)

Comment: Sorry its still same error...

Comment: Instead of import spmoduleloader, can you try import moduleloader and use it in the render method ?

Comment: I did and its same. how did you use it ? can you share any working copy ?

Comment: I used the spmoduleloader and its working. Also, did you check config.json ? Are you on rc0 ? Try running gulp serve again after changing code.

Comment: After adding/changing import statement, you need to stop gulp and start gulp serve again.

Comment: I did it but still same something wrong maybe my npm version dunno, can you try this repo? https://github.com/y3n3rrr/SPFxAnnouncements/ And tell me the results you get? simply clone it and you know rest of("npm install" , "gulp serve")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52482/discussion-between-tyforhelpdude-and-gautam-sheth).

Comment: @TyForHelpDude - remove the `sp-loader` entry from config.json !

Comment: I really appreciated your help and your efford. I will remember your name and seeking a chance to do same favor. It works now, Thank you!